# SQL statement queries parameters become case sensitive how so?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm running a SQL query on my mysql database but for some reason its case sensitive like if an entry exists as 'NAME = Andrew' running a sql query like:

```
SELECT * WHERE NAME Like 'and%'
```

Doesn't work but

```
SELECT * WHERE NAME Like 'And%'
```

does work? WHat gives I'm running a php mysql set up here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your field's collation. For instance if you use utf8_general_ci for the 'name' field, it would be case insensitive on that query.

Comment: utf8_genderal_ci will also treat "He%" and "She%" as equal. ;)

Comment: in particular, collations containing near the end _ci are case insensitive, and those containing _cs are case sensitive

Comment: Sorry for that genderal typo ;-)

Comment: WHOA! Spot on - my fields we collated with utf8_bin - I'll change them to something which ends with ci :) Thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL Dev Site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

"Normally, if any expression in a string comparison is case sensitive, the comparison is performed in case-sensitive fashion. "

Answer (score 0):

> Normally, if any expression in a
>   string comparison is case sensitive,
>   the comparison is performed in
>   case-sensitive fashion.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Yet, someone thinks it is a bug
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8847